# How would I instantiate several accounts from a bank account class?

Tags: python

I have to write code to instantiate several objects (bank accounts) from a class. I wrote the functions for checking the balance, withdrawing, and depositing with a single object. However, I can't figure how to make it so that the class is repeated for each object. I also can't figure out how to make it so that the choice to check the balance, deposit, or withdraw from the object applies to the correct object. In addition to this, I don't know how to get the functions to check the balance, deposit, and withdraw to run for each object.

Code:

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, name, account_number, balance):
    print("Welcome to the bank.")
    self.name=name
    self.account_number=account_number
    self.balance=balance
    


  def check_balance(self):
    print ("Balance:", self.balance)

  def deposit(self):
    print("Current balance:", self.balance)
    str2=input("How much would you like to deposit? ")
    str2=int(str2)
    print ("Current Balance:", self.balance + str2)

  def withdraw(self):
    print ("Current Balance", self.balance)
    str4=input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")
    str4=int(str4)
    if self.balance - str4 < 0:
      print("Unable to process. Doing this will result in a negative balance.")
    elif self.balance - str4 >= 0:
      print("Current Balance:", self.balance - str4)


  str3=input("Would you like to check the balance of the account, deposit money into the account, or withdraw money from the account? ")

  if str3=="check the balance":
    self.check_balance()

  elif str3=="deposit money":
    self.deposit()

  elif str3=="withdraw money":
    self.withdraw()

  else:
    print("Unable to process.")

Fred=Account("Fred",20,30)
John=Account("John",30,40)
Michelle=Account("Michelle",40,50)
Ann=Account("Ann",50,60)
```

Comment: "In addition to this, I don't know how to get the functions to check the balance, deposit, and withdraw to run for each object." then you haven't got the program running for even a single account, so why ask about how to deal with multiple accounts?

Comment: Your `deposit` function doesn't actually do anything other than print the result. It doesn't change the value

Answer (score 0):

You have some design problems here.

1. Don't store the accounts in 4 separate variables.  Store them in a list so you can look them up by account number (or by name, if you want to add that).  That will make it easier to save the accounts to file and read them back, which you will need to do.
2. The `Account` is just a place to store information.  Don't have it do any I/O.  Don't have it interact with the user.
3. You need to ask the user which account to work with.
4. You should loop until they're done.

Here, I'm asking for an account number every time.  To make this smarter, you would ask for an account one, and keep allowing options on that account, with another menu item to switch to a different account.

You COULD store the accounts in a dictionary with the account number as the key.  That would be more sensible than a simple list.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, account_number, balance):
        self.name=name
        self.account_number=account_number
        self.balance=balance

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self,amt):
        if self.balance < amt:
            return self.balance - amt
        self.balance -= amt
        return self.balance


accounts = [
    Account("Fred",20,30),
    Account("John",30,40),
    Account("Michelle",40,50),
    Account("Ann",50,60)
]

print("Welcome to the bank.")
while True:
    acct = int(input("Which account number are you working with today? "))
    acct = [a for a in accounts if a.account_number == acct]
    if not acct:
        print("That account doesn't exist.")
        continue
    acct = acct[0]

    print("\nBalance: ", acct.balance)
    print("Would you like to:")
    print(" 1. Check the balance")
    print(" 2. Deposit money")
    print(" 3. Withdraw money")
    print(" 4. Quit")
    str3 = input("Pick in option: ")
    if str3=="1":
        print("Balance: ", acct.balance)

    elif str3=="2":
        amt=int(input("How much would you like to deposit? "))
        acct.deposit( amt )

    elif str3=="3":
        amt=int(input("How much would you like to withdraw? "))
        if acct.withdraw( amt ) < 0:
            print("Unable to process. Doing this will result in a negative balance.")

    elif str3=="4":
        break

    else:
        print("Unrecognized.")
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic in your `withdraw()` function?

Comment: (also, IMHO it's not good form to overload a single variable `acct` with three different data types; an integer, a list of accounts, and finally an account...)

Comment: If the withdrawal would cause us to be overdrawn, I do not do the withdrawal, and instead return the amount of the excess as a negative number so the caller can take some action.  One could also just return `True`/`False` as a success/failure signal.

Comment: I'd document that as a comment - or better yet `raise Overdraw()`...